# Number elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to learn more about list replacement without using `Table`. I have a list like this:

```
list = {{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}}
```

Now, I want to modify the list elements, i.e. add the position of the respective elements in front of it and replace every element in the list with that:

```
listMod = {{{1->"a", 2->"b",3->"c"}, {1->"d", 2->"e", 3->"f"}, {1->"g", 2->"h", 3->"i"}}}
```

Comment: Check `MapIndexed`.

Comment: Ah yes that works quite well, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
list = {{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}};
Map[MapIndexed[First@#2 -> #1 &], #, {2}] &@list

(* Out: {{{1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, {1 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"},
        {1 -> "g", 2 -> "h", 3 -> "i"}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't about `MapIndexed` until now ;)

Comment: @holistic You are very welcome :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}};


Apply[Rule, Map[Transpose[{Range@3, #}] &, list, {2}], {3}]
```

[image]

Or, more generally

```
num[v_] := Thread[Range@Length@v -> v]

num /@ Catenate@list
```

Or

```
Normal @ Map[PositionIndex, list, {2}] /. (a_ -> {b_}) :> b -> a
```

Comment: Wow, thanks still trying to understand the last line ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
MapIndexed[#2[[3]] -> #1 &, list, {3}]
```

> {{{1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, {1 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 
>      3 -> "f"}, {1 -> "g", 2 -> "h", 3 -> "i"}}}

**Original answer**

```
Map[Thread[Range@Length@# -> #] &, list, {2}]
```

```
MapIndexed[#2[[3]] -> #1 &, list, {3}] == 
Map[Thread[Range@Length@# -> #] &, list, {2}] == listMod
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ReplacePart` :

```
list = {{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}}
ReplacePart[list,x:{i_,j_,k_}:> (k-> Extract[list,x])]
```

> {{{1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, {1 -> "d", 2 -> "e",     3 -> "f"},
>   {1 -> "g", 2 -> "h", 3 -> "i"}}}

`ReplacePart[]` is known to be not efficient in terms of memory consumption and speed.

The advantage here is that you have a great flexiblity to do more complicated remplacements. For example you can put constraints on the patterns `i_`,`j_`,`k_`,`x`

Answer (score 3):

```
Module[{i = 1}, i++ -> # & /@ #] & /@ # & /@ list
```

> {{{1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, {1 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"}, {1 -> "g", 2 -> "h", 3 -> "i"}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[Rule, {ConstantArray[Range[#3],
     {#, #2}] & @@ Dimensions[list], list}, 3]
```

> {{{1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, {1 -> "d", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "f"}, {1 -> "g", 2 -> "h", 3 -> "i"}}}

Answer (score 2):

Missed the boat on this... The only thing I can think of that hasn't already appeared is

```
List@Transpose[With[{i = #}, i -> # & /@ list[[1, ;; , i]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

Although `& / @ {1, 2, 3}` is basically `Table`, so I don't know if it counts.