# How can I extract parts from a ragged nested list?

Tags: partitions

I have given the following list

```
list = {a, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}
```

Is there a direct way to use `Part` specification to get e.g. `{a,b,e}` or `{a,c,f}`. I know about `Flatten` or `Append` of course, but want to avoid it in my specific case.

Something like

```
list[[1, {{2, 1}, {3, 1}}]]
```

doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: `Extract[list, {{1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}]` yields `{a,b,e}`.

Comment: So often I hear people ask "How do I do X?" in Mathematica when the answer is simply "Use the function that is called `X`".

Answer (score 11):

Using `Part` you could do something like the following:

```
list = {a, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}
Part[list, ##] & @@ # & /@ {{1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}

(* Out[22]= {a, b, e} *)
```

but then again, `Extract` is the builtin with exactly this functionality:

```
Extract[list, {{1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}]
(* Out[23]= {a, b, e} *)
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers/comments. I think I will deal with `Extract` then, though need to map it somehow, since I can not specify it manually for a huge array. This should be manageable though.

Comment: The first approach can be shortened to `Part[list, ##] & @@@ {{1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}`

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, although I am not sure I fully understand why.

```
#& @@@ list
```

> {a, b, e}

```
#2 & @@@ list
```

> {a, c, f}

In addition (etc):

```
#3 & @@@ list
```

> {a, d, h}

**Original Attempt**

```
list // Flatten[{#[[1]], #[[2 ;;, 1]]}] &
```

> {a, b, e}

```
list // Flatten[{#[[1]], #[[2 ;;, 2]]}] &
```

> {a, c, f}

Comment: it works like that because `@@@` means `Apply` at the second level, so that `f @@@ {{a}, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}` is equivalent to `{f[a], f[b, c, d, e], f[e, f, h, i]}`. When you then write `#i & @@@ list` you are asking for the $i$-th element of the arguments in the `f` example above

Comment: @glS - From documentation for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html): "`Apply[f, expr, {1}]` or `f @@@ expr` replaces heads at level **1** of expr by f."

Comment: @glS In addition to Bob Hanlon's comment,`list` is {a, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}} not {{a}, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}.  For example, `Flatten[{{a}, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}, {{2}}][[1]]` works for part one of OP, but `Flatten[list, {{2}}]` gives an error. Even if we accept that `#& @@@ list` should (?) work, I (naively?) expected `#2& @@@ list` to give an error.  But thanks for your comment. Obviously I am missing something ...

Comment: @tomd  From the docs of Apply -> possible issues :  "Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing:  `f@@a (* a *)`.    Of course, this gets into the question/issue of what exactly a subpart of an atom is, but at least it's clear what happens to symbols.

Comment: Btw, Big +1, because I use Apply all the time and never knew it had this effect on symbols.

Comment: @jjc385  I think you are right, that explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ReplacePart` may be interesting for complicated ragged nested list :

```
list = {a, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}
Reap[ReplacePart[list,x: Alternatives[{1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}] :> Sow[Extract[list,x]]]][[2,1]]
```

> {a, b, e}

One advantage is that there isn't any warning message if some specified parts do not exist.

Other advantages/drawbacks are given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154003/5467)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}};

Extract[list, #] & /@ Table[{{1}, {2, i}, {3, i}}, {i, 4}]
```

or equivalently

```
  Extract[list, #] & /@ {{1}, {2, #}, {3, #}} & /@ Range@4
```

> ```
> {{a, b, e}, {a, c, f}, {a, d, h}, {a, e, i}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you you create a list for the first parameter a->{a,a,a,a} the solution of your problem is

```
Transpose[{{a, a, a, a}, {b, c, d, e}, {e, f, h, i}}]
```