# How to specify Part in [[{...}]] at mixed levels?

Tags: list-manipulation

In the following example, how to easily get `{2,4,10}` using the `[[{...}]]` syntax?

```
aa = {2, 4, 6, {8, 10, 12}, 14, 16, 18, 20};
aa[[{1, 2}]]
(*{2,4}*)
aa[[{1, 2(* what to put here?? *)}]]
(*{2,4,10}*)
aa[[{1, 2(* what to put here?? *)}]]
(*{2,4,{10,12}}*)
```

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible with `Part`. Use `Extract` instead: `Extract[aa, {{1}, {2}, {4, 2}}]`.

Comment: if one is allowed to use Flatten, then `Flatten[{aa[[{1, 2}]], aa[[{1, 2, 4}]][[3, 2]]}]` gives `{2, 4, 10}`  but I would also use `Extract`, much simpler.

Comment: `Join[aa[[{1, 2}]], {aa[[4, 2]]}]`

Comment: `aa[[##]]&@@@ {1,2, {4, 2}}` after [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160991/106)

Comment: As @HenrikSchumacher noted: `Part` is not the right tool for the job here; it cannot mix and match levels in this way. `Extract` is the correct function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Part[Flatten[aa], #] & /@ {1, 2, 5}

(*  {2, 4, 10}  *)
```

If you need to first determine the positions of the desired elements do first

```
pos = Position[Flatten[aa], #] & /@ {2, 4, 10} // Flatten

(* {1, 2, 5}  *)
```

and then

```
Part[Flatten[aa], #] & /@ pos

(*  {2, 4, 10}   *)
```

Have fun!